# AJAX call returns 'testtest0' instead of 'test' - why?

Tags: plugin-development, ajax

I am expecting the following code to alert 'test', instead it alerts 'testtest0'. Why?

The code runs some javascript in the admin footer, it's response is just echoed via the functions `test()` and `get_test()`;

```
<?php

class Test_Class {

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'admin_footer', array( $this, 'test_js' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_test', array( $this, 'test' ) );
    }

    public function test_js() { 
        global $post; ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

                function runTest() {

                    var data = {
                        'action': 'test',
                    };

                    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                        alert( response );
                    });

                }

                runTest();

            });
        </script>
    <?php }

    public function test() {

        $test = $this->get_test();
        echo $test;

    }

    public function get_test() {

        $string = 'test';
        return $string;

    }

}

$new = new Test_Class();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax callbacks should always finish with a `die()`, otherwise it will output that 0 you are seeing. I'm not sure why it's outputting another "test"

Comment: Yes that fixes the end 0, but why the loop of testtest?